# supervisord : starting consul spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'consul': EROFS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, supervisord, consul

I am starting the `consul` process using `supervisor` in Docker and running it in Kubernetes environment. when I test with `docker run` it starts the process. but Kubernetes pod process is not starting. throwing below error.

Its not showing any file system related error message,  when get the shell to pod and run the `consul` program it works.

```
2023-09-01 20:34:59,344 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/consul-supervisord.conf" during parsing
2023-09-01 20:34:59,345 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2023-09-01 20:35:00,347 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'consul': EROFS
2023-09-01 20:35:01,348 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'consul': EROFS
2023-09-01 20:35:03,351 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'consul': EROFS
2023-09-01 20:35:06,354 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making dispatchers for 'consul': EROFS
2023-09-01 20:35:06,354 INFO gave up: consul entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2023-09-01 20:44:59,969 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
```

How to see `EROFS` error message? any other tips to see detailed error message during startup?

Thanks